# Using a double value in Thread.sleep() function java

Tags: java

Basically my issue is that I have a random number generator that generates a random `double` value between the user given int +- 0.5:

```
double actualClickInterval = (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(clickinterval - 0.5, clickinterval + 0.5 +1));
```

Where `clickinterval` is the user given int.

This double value is supposed to be passed to `Thread.sleep()`, which requires a Long value instead. If I convert it to a Long value, the decimals disappear. Is there any way around this?

Current Thread.sleep() code is as follows:

```
Thread.sleep((long)actualClickInterval * 1000 - 500);
```

I need the value to be a double, because the performed task needs to be done with random delays that are < 500ms long. Any other methods of doing this are welcome as well.

Comment: Seems like you'd need to revisit a tutorial on Java integer math. Besides that, try casting the result of the calculation to `long` instead of the parameter: `(long)(actualClickInterval * 1000 - 500)`.

Comment: Convert the **result** to a long: `Thread.sleep((long) (actualClickInterval * 1000 - 500));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First multiply by `1000`, *then* convert to `long`:

```
Thread.sleep((long)(actualClickInterval * 1000) - 500);
```

If you first convert, you make `1` from `1.3`, times `1000` is `1000`. If you first multiply, you do `1.3 * 1000`, which is `1300.0`, and converted to `long`, that makes `1300`.